# NDSolve fails to solve partial differential equation

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics, pde

When solving a partial differential equation, I get

> NDSolve::eerri: Warning: estimated initial error on the specified spatial grid in the direction of independent variable x exceeds prescribed error tolerance. And the equation cannot be solved.

My code:

```
ClearAll
l = 2.5
l0 = 1.5
Eb = 210*1000000000
rb = 10/1000
rhob = 7850
Eg = 35*1000000000
rg = 17.5/1000
vg = 0.25
varphi = 45/180*Pi
Cb = 2*Pi*rb
Ab = Pi*rb^2
R = 10*Eb*rb/((Eg + xE)/2)
Gg = Eg/(2*(1 + vg))
k = Gg*G/((G*Log[rg/rb] + Gg*Log[R/rb])*rb)
YiTa = Tan[varphi]
z1 = b
p[x_, t_] = FullSimplify[YiTa*Sigmaz[r0 + l - x, z1, t]]
PDE1 = D[u1[x, t], {x, 2}] == 
  rhob*D[u1[x, t], {t, 2}]/Eb + k*Cb*u1[x, t]/(Eb*Ab) + 
   p[x, t]*Cb/(Eb*Ab)
initialCondition = {Derivative[0, 1][u1][x, 0] == 
   Vr[r0 + l - x, z1, 0], u1[x, 0] == Ur[r0 + l - x, z1, 0]}
boundaryConditions = {u1[0, t] == Ur[l + r0, z1, t], 
  u1[l0, t] == Ur[r0 + l - l0, z1, t]}
sol = NDSolve[{PDE1, initialCondition, boundaryConditions}, 
  u1, {x, 0, l0}, {t, 0, 0.001}, MaxStepSize -> 0.0000001]
Plot3D[Evaluate[u1[x, t] /. sol], {x, 0, l0}, {t, 0, 0.0001}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "u1(x,t)"}]
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBTQ6.png)

I tried running the code but got no results. I hope to get results that can be run and plotted.

Comment: Your `ClearAll` use doesn't match the latest documentation. You are using `=` to define functions instead of `:=`, If you display `{PDE1, initialCondition, boundaryConditions}` before you try `NDSolve` you have extra `{}` in that which may not match documentation. You have large and small decimal numbers and fractional powers of those which may be causing your error message. Try replacing all decimals with exact rationals, which may make some things better, but others worse. That will let you try adding `WorkingPrecision->64` to `NDSolve` and see if that gets you anywhere.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your post is [missing some text](/help/how-to-ask). All you did was paste your code and the error you got, so you still need to talk about why you wrote the code that you're showing and what debugging and (re)searching you already did. Because right now your post _doesn't contain a question_, so there's nothing for anyone to answer or help with.

Comment: Looks like you have made a good effort to solve a complex problem. My advice is to back up and try a very simple version first, and then increasingly complex versions until you get back to the full problem.

Comment: There is no error in the code, but it just can’t be solved. I can’t solve it in the NDSolve part. I would like to ask if there is any way to get the numerical solution.

Answer (score 1):

Too long to put in a comment. As I earlier suggested, I replaced your `$MachinePrecision` constants with exact rationals.

```
mu=25/100;rho=2350;xE=18*10^9;G=xE/(2*(1+mu));cp=Sqrt[xE*(1-mu)/(rho*(1+mu)*(1-2*mu))];
r0=25/10;xdb=40/1000;xdp=25/10*40/1000;rho0=1100;xD=3200;sb=4500/1000;r0=25/10;
b=15/10;alpha=4000;
JM=(3*Pi)/(4*r0);m=alpha/cp;j=Sqrt[JM^2+m^2];A0=xdb/(8*sb)*rho0*xD^2/(xdp/xdb)^(22/10);
A=(1-E^(-b*j))*xE((j^2-m^2+(2*j^2-3*m^2)*mu)/Sqrt[r0]*Cos[Sqrt[j^2-m^2]*r0-
  Pi/4]/(1-2*mu)-Sqrt[j^2-m^2]*r0^(-3/2)*Sin[Sqrt[j^2-m^2]*r0-Pi/4]-(3-5*mu)*
  r0^(-5/2)*Cos[Sqrt[j^2-m^2]*r0-Pi/4]/(4*(1-2*mu)))/(b*j*(1+mu));A1=A0/A;
Ur[r_,z_,t_]=A1*(1/2*Cos[Sqrt[j^2-m^2]*r-1/4*Pi]/r^(3/2)+Sqrt[j^2-m^2]*
  Sin[Sqrt[j^2-m^2]*r-1/4*Pi]/Sqrt[r])*E^(-j*z)*E^(-m*cp*t);
Vr[r_,z_,t_]:=-m*cp*A1*(1/2*Cos[Sqrt[j^2-m^2]*r-1/4*Pi]/r^(3/2)+Sqrt[j^2-
  m^2]*Sin[Sqrt[j^2-m^2]*r-1/4*Pi]/Sqrt[r])*E^(-j*z)*E^(-m*cp*t);
Sigmaz[r_,z_,t_]:=xE*A1*((-j^2+(2*j^2-m^2)*mu)*Cos[Sqrt[j^2-m^2]*r-1/4*Pi]/
  ((1-2*mu)*Sqrt[r])-mu*Cos[Sqrt[j^2-m^2]*r-1/4*Pi]/((4-8*mu)*r^(5/2)))*
  E^(-j*z)*E^(-m*cp*t)/(1+mu);
l=25/10;l0=15/10;Eb=210*10^9;rb=10/1000;rhob=7850;Eg=35*10^9;rg=175/10/1000;
vg=025/100;varphi=45/180*Pi;Cb=2*Pi*rb;Ab=Pi*rb^2;R=10*Eb*rb/((Eg+xE)/2);
Gg=Eg/(2*(1+vg));k=Gg*G/((G*Log[rg/rb]+Gg*Log[R/rb])*rb);YiTa=Tan[varphi];z1=b;
p[x_,t_]:=YiTa*Sigmaz[r0+l-x,z1,t];
PDE1={D[u1[x,t],{x,2}]==rhob*D[u1[x,t],t,2}]/Eb+k*Cb*u1[x,t]/(Eb*Ab)+
  p[x,t]*Cb/(Eb*Ab)};
initialCondition={Derivative[0,1][u1][x,0]==Vr[r0+l-x,z1,0],u1[x,0]==Ur[r0+l-x,z1,0]};
boundaryConditions={u1[0,t]==Ur[l+r0,z1,t],u1[l0,t]==Ur[r0+l-l0,z1,t]};
sys=Simplify[N[Join[PDE1,initialCondition,boundaryConditions],64]]
```

Just before the step of doing the `NDSolve` that displays (roughly)

```
{Derivative[2, 0][u1][x, t] == (     
0.00545860389386734035988805739383977751117746615039472979478311832031082160733*
(25.035720659226906140411453104565220866207337272409961236398875988369353985859-
10.*x + 1.*x^2)*Cos[
3.9269908169872415480783042290993786052464617492188822762186807403847705078577- 
.94247779607693797153879301498385086525915081981253174629248337769234492*x])/    
(E^(3999.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999*t)* 
(5. - 1.*x)^(5/2)) +    
147.137927874474292837143887032039529266866273227161600896429319953505602294*
u1[x, t] + 3.738095238095238095238095238095238095238095238095238095238095238*^
-8*Derivative[0, 2][u1][x, t], 
Derivative[0, 1][u1][x, 0] == -(((       
(1.6768709894289540203312443887507074674202073320420657991243447623718564+ 0.*I)- 
0.30320332583960679232662864081734027262650464178210400129298177083547+0.*I)*x)*
Cos[0.9424777960769379715387930149838508652591508198125317462924833776923*x] + 
((-1.3551622689671139029350420194226952588448390857789742138054729459828 +0.*I) + 
(0.303203325839606792326628640817340272626504641782104001292981770835+0.*I)*x)*
Sin[0.94247779607693797153879301498385086525915081981253174629248337769*x])/
(5. - 1.*x)^(3/2)), 
u1[x, 0] == -((( 
(-0.00041921774735723850508281109718767686685505183301051644978108619059+0.*I) +
(0.00007580083145990169808165716020433506815662616044552600032324544 +0.*I)*x)*
Cos[0.9424777960769379715387930149838508652591508198125317462924833776923*x] + 
((0.000338790567241778475733760504855673814711209771444743553451368236495+0.*I)- 
(0.0000758008314599016980816571602043350681566261604455260003232454427+0.*I)*x)*
Sin[0.942477796076937971538793014983850865259150819812531746292483377688587*x])/
(5. - 1.*x)^(3/2)), 
u1[0, t] == 
0.000037495975218604724441921501083994167027199906049745772524411502557/
E^(3999.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999993*t),
u1[1.5, t] == 
-0.00002665354928541077808491725593466020104224160610364654413085048230532/
E^(3999.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999993*t)}
```

Most of that looks reasonable, except for the E^(3999.99999...*t) terms
and all "approximately 0*I" terms.

Can you work through the changes I made, see if I made any mistake doing this, and get rid of those terms that scare me?

I have not removed those, but I have tried the handful of tricks that I've used in the past and it either takes so much time or memory or bails out with the warning about the error being too large.

Is it possible to come up with a substantially simpler system that still correctly represents what you are trying to give `NDSolve`? If you can do that then that might enable it to solve for you.